# How do I make two relativelayouts show as top and bottom on a linearlayout versus side by side, programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a linearlayout as a container for two relativelayouts.  Both relativelayouts appear on the screen but they are side by side.  I want them to be top and bottom.  It looks as if the linearlayout initialization defaults to Horizontal.  I have tried using setorientation to Vertical but the screen blanks out. 
The following code is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
   LinearLayout layoutContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    //layoutContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    // Arguments here: width, height, weight
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childLp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);

    layoutTop = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layoutContainer.addView(layoutTop, childLp);

    layoutBot = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layoutContainer.addView(layoutBot, childLp);

    layoutTop.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);
    layoutBot.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    setContentView(layoutContainer);
```

Comment: relative layouts need width and height definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks as if the linearlayout initialization defaults to Horizontal.

That is exactly right.

> I have tried using setorientation to Vertical but the screen blanks out.

You do need to set `orientation` to `vertical` to get this effect. As for it "blanks out", I see several things wrong such as setting the `width` to "0". There is no `width` so it won't show anything. I think you would want something like `LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT`. Also, you are using `LinearLayout` `params` for your `RelativeLayout` which may or may not make a difference in this case.

If there isn't a necessary reason to create the `layout` in Java it is much easier to do this in the xml.

Comment: You'll get it, just make sure you understand what you are changing every time and ask if you don't and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating your layouts by trying to programmatically manipulate them. Set the orientation to `Vertical` and do the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    ------
    ------  
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Your first Relative layout

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ----------------------
    ---------------------
                   />
```

Your next Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel2"
    android:layout_below="@id/rel1"
    ----------------------
    ---------------------
                      />
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` doesn't have the properties `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Comment: if you see my answer, I've given them in relative layout. My answer works, just tested it. :)

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work but those properties won't do anything when the `RelativeLayout`s parent isn't a `RelativeLayout`. The `layout` properties come from the parent `layout`.

Comment: Yeah that's true.But that would be a problem only when you want to manipulate views, programmatically right? Sorry, I'm quite new to android :P

Comment: No need to be sorry, and no. Try using these properties inside of a `LinearLayout` parent then take them out. They will not provide any functionality. The `layout` properties adjust that `View` inside of its parent so they only apply if there parent has those properties.

Comment: For instance, you could use `layout_weight` here because the parent is a `LinearLayout` and that is a property of `LinearLayout`. If the parent was `RelativeLayout` then `layout_weight` wouldn't do anything for it, anything useful anyway